# How to embed links in localized text

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internationalization, hyperlink

I am internationalizing an ASP.NET MVC application, but I'm unsure how to handle linked text. Take the following as an example:

- English: "Please [login](https://www.example.com/Login) to continue."
- Português: "[Entre](https://www.example.com/Login) por favor para continuar."

Since "login" is hyperlinked, I must have the translator mark which corresponding word or phrase should be hyperlinked when the text is localized, e.g. Entre.

What is the best strategy-solution?

Is there a standard way to mark special text (and a standard way of using the translated results) ... or have I gone down the wrong path in expecting my content and presentation information to be so tightly coupled (although I can't think of any way to remove the coupling in this case).

**Current Implementation:**

I am currently using local resource files for Views and [an extension method on HtmlHelper](http://blog.eworldui.net/post/2008/10/ASPNET-MVC-Simplified-Localization-via-ViewEngines.aspx) to get the localized sting:

```
<%= Html.Resource("LoginMessage")%>
```

**Update:**
**Please see [Keith's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746693/how-to-embed-links-in-localized-text/1807773#1807773)**.

I found it most helpful, but the system [auto selected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4508/please-do-not-auto-select-answers-on-bounty-questions) another one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I'm currently using is he following setup:

I have a global resource file containing my primary texts, named Strings.resx (Strings.NL-nl.resx etc). Next to this I have my global file containing all localizations of my actionlinks. That is: ActionLinks.resx and locals.

Now what I do is, in my Strings.resx I have something like:

Strings.resx

> Please {0} to continue

Local language Strings.NL-nl.resx

> {0} om verder te gaan

Now the trick is to do something like:

```
<%= Html.Encode(string.Format(Resources.Strings.ControllernameViewnameKey, 
Html.ActionLink(Resources.ActionLinks.login, "Account", "LogOn")))
```

If you need more than one variable in your link you can give an array of objects to

```
 string.Format()
```

The keynaming is my own convention to understand where the maintext is used (what page). Since my maintexts are very specific. Of course keys can be made yourself.

For more information on how I do it you can have a look at my *answer* on my own question:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680268/asp-net-mvc-localization-why-do-it-the-difficult-way)

---

**Edit**

Of course you can use local files instead of global files but I like my strongly typed resources too much for that :).

Comment: I think separating the translations of the action links from the rest of the sentence could be risky. Your suggestion would always work if a sentence can be broken into segments, translated independently and pieced back together without introducing poor word choices and poor word ordering.  But since sentence structures are different from one language to the next and word choices are context sensitive, I think the sentences must be translated as a whole.  

Have you run across that problem?  Thanks for the input!  I like a lot of what you have done and it is defiantly helpful.

Comment: ... or perhaps "definitely" helpful.  :-)

Comment: Hm, what you say does make sense but I have not run into that problem yet. Maybe because I do not have that much of text which is static. If you find a solution for this be sure to message me I would love to hear one, because it indeed may be a problem.

Comment: In languages like German and English, a verb can be broken into two pieces that are not next to each other such as "Log the account for the application in". Of course in English we tend to prefer "Log in the account for the application", but other languages may not. In addition, some languages use a non-root form of a word such as the Spanish example using "Entre" instead of "Entrar". The translator needs to see the whole sentence to know the correct word form to choose.

Answer (score 16):

I think this comes down to 4 choices:

1. Put a link in your localisation: "Please <a href="#">login</a> to continue"
2. Multiple localisations - either:

   1. "Please {0} to continue" and "login", or
   2. "Please", "login" and " to continue"
3. Markup inside your localisations, for instance:

   1. "Please {0}login{1} to continue"
   2. "Please {start-login}login{end-login} to continue"
   3. "Please <a href="{0}">login</a> to continue"
4. Just don't support it - make the whole sentence a link

I think there is a major reason to avoid 1 - you mix up localisations and application navigation.

Option 2 ends up with multiple resources for each block of text, but as long as you have good ways of managing all your localisations it shouldn't be an issue. It can be a pain for 3rd-party translators though - you need some way to tell them the context or you get some very weird translations of the individual words.

Option 3 is my preferred solution. You still create issues for your translators though - most will not understand your tokens/HTML/markup in the text. Ours already do some HTML, so 3.3 has worked for us.

Option 4 might be worth considering - do you gain enough in having the link embedded in order to make it worth the extra work and maintenance? It's an important question specific to your application: *if the whole sentence is the link (rather than just the active verb - which is link best practice) do you really lose enough to make option 2 or 3 worth the additional effort?*

I think this might be why there aren't more standardised ways of doing this as for most projects (maybe 9 times out of 10) option 4 is sufficient, so this only ends up as a problem for some special cases. We have a complex application with around 11,000 pieces of localised text and go for 4 the vast majority of the time, and have only 4 or 5 places where we've had to go with 3.3

Our technical implementation is similar to yours:

```
<%= Html.Localise("Controller/Action/KeyOfTextOnPage") %>
```

For links we have a specific helper:

```
<%= Html.LocaliseLink("Controller/Action/KeyOfTextOnPage", "~/link.aspx") %>
<%= Html.LocaliseAction("Controller/Action/KeyOfTextOnPage", "action", "controller") %>
```

Comment: Excellent response!  Our translators can work around html tags and we have decided use 3.3 in most instances.  This is working well.

Answer (score 2):

I have to agree with other answers - separate in 2.

That said I would add that don't consider the 2 words separated / unrelated. Stick to a simple convention all around like: LoginMessage & LoginMessageLink, corresponding to the whole text of the sentence & the text of the link.

That's neutral & if that's what needed for the language the translator can have the whole sentence be the link.

If you find yourself needing to link several times to the same page, then instead have some markers for it. Like:

```
English: "Please ##login## to continue."
Português: "##Entre## por favor para continuar."
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but I figured this might help.

In ASP.net Core 2.2, you can have a resource file containing:

```
AllText: There are 2 links and one string. Links are {0} and {1}, the string is {2}
Link1Text: link1
Link2Text: link2
String1: something special
```

Then you have the view where you inject the localizer:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization

@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
```

And finally in your HTML:

```
<p>@Localizer["AllText",
       @Html.ActionLink(@Localizer["Link1Text"].Value,"Action1","Controller1"),
       @Html.ActionLink(@Localizer["Link2Text"].Value,"Action2","Controller2"),
       @Localizer["String1"]]</p>
```

No need to encode or decode anything, just provide the parameters to the Localizer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest separating the resource into two values, like this
- 1: Please {0} to continue.
- 2: login

or for Português
- 1: {0} por favor para continuar.
- 2: Entre

And then combine them to build the link and message. {0} is substitued for the link/actionlink/whatever you need.

Comment: Thank you for posting.  See my comment on bastijn's post about the risks of poor word choice or word order with translations that are not done in complete sentences.  I think that would apply here as well.

Comment: Definitely. We've suggested basically the same solution. I'd say that in the example, you can't reuse the strings for 1-2 for anything else.

Answer (score 1):

I'd simply look for custom placeholders that index to the link that you want placed around the text. Eg

```
"Please #123#login#123# to continue"
```

If you find #n# in your string, you know that the string that it surrounds should be a link to the url specified by index n in your lookup file (db, or whatever).

Answer (score 1):

Here's my quick and dirty implementation on .NET 6:

Extension method in the `IHtmlLocalizser`:

```
public static class IHtmlLocalizerExtensions
{
    public static LocalizedHtmlString Links(this IHtmlLocalizer localizer, string text, params Func<string, IHtmlContent>[] links)
    {
        var index = 0;
        var localized = Regex.Replace(localizer[text].Value, "<(.+?)>", match =>
        {
            var linkText = match.Groups[1].Value;
            var link = links[index++](linkText);
            return GetHtml(link);
        });
        return new LocalizedHtmlString(text, localized);
    }

    private static string GetHtml(IHtmlContent content)
    {
        using var writer = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        content.WriteTo(writer, HtmlEncoder.Default);
        return writer.ToString();
    }
}
```

Use it like this in your views:

```
@inject IViewLocalizer localizer

<div class="terms">
    @localizer.Links("By logging in, you agree to our <Terms of Use> and <Privacy Policy>.",
        x => Html.ActionLink(x, "TermsOfUse", "Home"),
        x => Html.ActionLink(x, "PrivacyPolicy", "Home"))
</div>
```